The compression rates of different nodes vary greatly
The compression rates of different nodes vary greatly.I deployed a 3meta+2data cluster, wrote 2t of data, and then waited for the written data to be compiled.During the subsequent compression process, I checked the reduced delta files.It was found that the compression speed of the two nodes is very different.
The statistics are as follows:
ubuntu20# find data/cnosdb/1001 -type f -name "*delta"| wc -l
725
ubuntu20# find data/cnosdb/2001 -type f -name "*delta"| wc -l
6773
ubuntu20# cat data/cnosdb/1001/log/tsdb.log.2024-04-22 | grep total_cost| wc -l
326
ubuntu20# cat data/cnosdb/2001/log/tsdb.log.2024-04-22 | grep total_cost| wc -l
14
ubuntu20# cat data/cnosdb/1001/log/tsdb.log.2024-04-21 | grep total_cost| wc -l
1892
ubuntu20# cat data/cnosdb/2001/log/tsdb.log.2024-04-21 | grep total_cost| wc -l
152
ubuntu20# cat data/cnosdb/1001/log/tsdb.log.2024-04-20 | grep total_cost| wc -l
1449
ubuntu20# cat data/cnosdb/2001/log/tsdb.log.2024-04-20 | grep total_cost| wc -l
110

These two data nodes are on the same physical machine, and the data directories of the two nodes are on the same disk, but why are the compression rates so different? Does anyone know what causes this?
